# for of loop unable to loop through values of an object which has been treated as an array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, for-of-loop

The `renderRow()` is a method in a React class component which is to get key-values of the state operators object and pass the values of the object into a react component `arithmeticComponent` to be rendered but its unable to produce the values after calling a for loop upon each map on the key. the issue is the value of the object is unable to be passed as a prop into the `arithmeticComponent`

```
 state = {
        operators: {
          topOperators: ["C", "Mod", "<"],
          numbers: ["%", ".", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        },
      };




 renderRow() {
        {
          Object.entries(this.state.operators).map((entry, index) => {
            //   console.log(entry);
            let key = entry[0];
    
            let value = entry[1];
            console.log(value);
    
            for (let val of value) {
              console.log(value.length);
              //console.log(key, value);
              return (
                <Row className="Row">
                  {console.log(val)}
                  <ArithmeticComponent key={index} operator={val} value={val} />;
                </Row>
              );
            }
    
            console.log(key, value);
          });
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check your logic at **return** statement. Did you mean `value.map((val)=><Row... )` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
     state = {
        operators: {
          topOperators: ["C", "Mod", "<"],
          numbers: ["%", ".", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        },
      };




 renderRow() {
          return Object.values(this.state.operators).map((value) => value.map(v=>(
               <Row className="Row">
                  <ArithmeticComponent key={v} operator={v} value={v} />;
                </Row>
            ))
          );
        }
```

use the return statement in Array.map carefully

and should not use `index` be the key

Comment: this worked out for me... thank you sir/madam